# How to create and download image from Docker container running in Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Imaging following scenario everyone can stack in production:

- we are running Elastic search as docker containers, indexing some
  data we would like to backup data every 3 months
- means we need to
  create docker image from running container and upload it to registry.

Haven't found any clues how to do that in documentation.

Answer (score 1):

With the swarm orchestration, your individual containers/tasks inside of the service may be restarted (e.g. if you have a node failure or your application crashes). For persistent data, I'd use an external volume and backup that volume directly. If you want to do this in swarm, you can commit the containers it creates by locating the specific container and committing it with the standard commands:

```
$ docker service create --name test-commit busybox /bin/sh -c 'while true; do ls / >/tmp/ls.`date +%T`.log; sleep 30; done'
2vbnf5s39vs0jfc53at3ko1cg

$ docker service ls
ID            NAME         REPLICAS  IMAGE    COMMAND
2vbnf5s39vs0  test-commit  1/1       busybox  /bin/sh -c while true; do ls / >/tmp/ls.`date +%T`.log; sleep 30; done

$ docker service ps test-commit
ID                         NAME           IMAGE    NODE              DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE          ERROR
eu28da042s9tdwlddzk6adkan  test-commit.1  busybox  docker-demo  Running        Running 9 seconds ago

$ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
545e7fe6f5bd        busybox:latest      "/bin/sh -c 'while tr"   28 seconds ago      Up 26 seconds                                test-commit.1.eu28da042s9tdwlddzk6adkan

$ docker diff test-commit.1.eu28da042s9tdwlddzk6adkan
C /tmp
A /tmp/ls.12:02:13.log
A /tmp/ls.12:02:43.log

$ docker commit test-commit.1.eu28da042s9tdwlddzk6adkan
 test-commit:1
sha256:2255b476b307b69cf20afbc7c46fae43f05c92a70f1525aa5d745c26a406dc90

$ docker images | grep test-commit
test-commit                           1                   2255b476b307        9 seconds ago       1.093 MB
```

Comment: just to clarify, by doing 'docker commit' 

I'll have to login to particular swarm node first? 
Result of commit will be new image of 'test-commit' container for this particular node?

Comment: Yes, you'd need to then `docker save` to a tar or `docker push` up to a registry server to use it elsewhere.

Comment: this is a bit drawback approach as for swarm and other container orchestration solutions, i'm not care about specific nodes when I do 'docker service create --replicas 10', but when I want to commit, I do need to find specific nodes where this 10 replicas running in

Comment: Yes, you're creating an anti-pattern in Swarm. As mentioned: "for persistent data, I'd use an external volume and backup that volume directly."

Comment: I didn't propose alternative approach. just saying that going down to each individual node and doing 'docker commit' is swarm anti pattern indeed, because when you working with cluster you should not manage individual node, externalize data in external volume is seems to be solution for me as well, just asking if swarm can help us with that, as far I know - no, only kubernetes can manage volumes on cluster level

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) to turn a container into an image.
But I would advise against doing that in this case. It's better to use some kind of volume for your data and back that up separately.

Comment: are you sure commit available in swarm?

Comment: Sorry, my fault - I need to read the header of your question as well.
I have little to no experience with Swarm, but I think it is still a good Idea to keep the actual data outside of the container.